# chrome javascript dom remove iframe backgroundimage

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, iframe

I've been messing with iframe for chrome extensions and I seem to be running into a lot of issues with iframes. Anyways, I have an iframe injected into a website(cross-domain). What I'd like is for the iframes background image to inherit the parents page background(So it blends in). So this is what I am trying:

```
//Setup iframe attributes
iframe.setAttribute("id","injected_frame");
iframe.setAttribute("src", 'google.com');
iframe.setAttribute("width","100%");
iframe.setAttribute("height","425");
iframe.setAttribute("frameborder","0");
iframe.setAttribute("scrolling","auto");
iframe.setAttribute("style","backgroundImage: inherit"); <-- undefined error
```

Basically it just doesn't work, background stays the same and I get an undefined error when trying this.

Comment: Oh I've also tried object.body.style, get's undefined error as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just change `"backgroundImage: inherit"` to `"background-image: inherit"`, but then any other inline styles on `iframe` may be lost because I believe that would reset the style attribute completely.

Thus, I would instead recommend replacing the last line with `iframe.style.backgroundImage = "inherit";`

Comment: Wait a minute, so you're trying to change the background of google.com when it's embedded in your iframe?  If that's the case, I don't believe it's possible with JS, due to cross-domain restrictions.  Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: Well the google part was just an example, but yes that's basically what I am trying to accomplish. I've googled it a lot and I get the same response about it not being possible due to cross domain restrictions. This is a google extension I am trying to make, Shouldn't the permissions line in the manifest.json file make this possible(Sofar I've had no luck)? I'll attempt to use a content script instead to force some css into the src url for the iframe. Hopefully that'll work.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention, I'm really not trying to change the background -- I just want it to be transparent inside the iframe so it'll blend in better.

Comment: I honestly don't know a whole lot about Chrome extensions, but based on this, it does appear that you can inject JavaScript and CSS once you include cross-domain permissions in your manifest.json: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi